# Node module. Private variables are reset

Tags: javascript, node.js

It seems as if my private variables in a node module are being "reset". E.g. I have the following code in a module

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;    

var process;

module.exports.start = function() {
    if (!process) {
        process = exec('Some process');
    }
};

module.exports.stop = function() {
    if (process) {
        process.kill();
    }
};
```

The problem that I am facing is that `process` variable is undefined if I call the `stop` function after the `start`.

Obviously the fix for this would be to define an object/class and expose that in the module.

But now I am curious to know how modules work in node. When a module is `require`'d, what happens to all the private variables?

Edit

I am using this module from the REPL to test, but an example usage would just be

```
var my_module = require('./my_module');

// the child process starts fine
my_module.start();

// after some time

// but does not end
my_module.stop();
```

Comment: Show the code that is using this module...

Comment: Maybe `exec` simply *does* return `undefined`?

Comment: Have shown an example. @Bergi no exec returns a ChildProcess object.

Comment: This works fine for me. What version of node are you using? Also, using `process` as your variable is a little sketchy since it would conflict with node's global [process](http://nodejs.org/api/process.html) object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the `node.js` documentation: http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html

> Variables local to the module will be private, as though the module was wrapped in a function.

So your variable basically exists only inside the clouse represented by the module.

Comment: But I am setting it in the `start` function. Since it is in the module closure should the `stop` function not pick up it's new value when called?

Comment: it should pick it up. You're pobably doing something else wrong. What does "after some time" mean?

Comment: I am running that code from the REPL, so in that case "after some time" is literal :)

Comment: do a `console.log` at the end of the `start` function, and at the beginning of the `stop`. If the first console.log shows some value, there's no way the second one is undefined (if you're running from REPL).

Comment: Ignore me. Was an issue with exec command. It was not being killed when told to do so! Moving to spawn fixed that issue.